# How can I change the color of the popup in SectionIndexer?

Tags: android, colors, android-widget

Below is the code of my adapter that allows to create a popup with the first letter of every item of my listview and provide something similar to the contact application.

[image]

Unfortunately, the colors are not correct and the text is black on a grey background.

My question is:

Where can I change these colors?

```
public class AlphabeticalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements
        SectionIndexer {

    HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;
    String[] sections;

    public AlphabeticalAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        int size = items.length;

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            String s = items[x];

            // get the first letter of the store
            String ch = s.substring(0, 1);
            // convert to uppercase otherwise lowercase a -z will be sorted
            // after upper A-Z
            ch = ch.toUpperCase();

            // HashMap will prevent duplicates
            alphaIndexer.put(ch, x);
        }

        Set<String> sectionLetters = alphaIndexer.keySet();

        // create a list from the set to sort
        ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionLetters);

        Collections.sort(sectionList);

        sections = new String[sectionList.size()];

        sectionList.toArray(sections);
    }

    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        return alphaIndexer.get(sections[section]);
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return 1;
    }

    public Object[] getSections() {
        return sections;
    }
}
```

Comment: From the looks of it I don't think you can do it. But here's an [alternative](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List9.html) you could customize the window accordingly but also note this wont snap according to sections.

Comment: This is the answer, you can post it and will accept ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it I don't think you can do it. But here's an [alternative](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List9.html) you could customize the window accordingly but also note this wont snap according to sections.